# How to investigate peak in MySQL throughput?

Tags: linux, mysql, performance, munin

Recently one of our servers has ran out of memory and crashed. After reviewing the `munin` graphs, it appears that the only metric (other than memory usage) that peaked just before the crash was the `MySQL throughput`. However we were expecting to see a corresponding increase in number of `MySQL queries` which didn't happen:

[image]

[image]

Also from below graph, you can see that the `MySQL throughput` has reached an abnormally high value, nowhere near any other value reached before:

[image]

We're completely in the dark as to how we should proceed, hence the below question:

**How to perform a "postmortem" investigation of a MySQL throughput increase?**

Comment: You simply can't if you have no (other) data!

Comment: That we figured out :) We have the bin logs in `/var/log/mysql/`, the error logs in `/var/log/mysqld.log`, we just have know idea as to how going about them, except based on timestamps, hence the question before we go down that time-consuming process.

Comment: Have you considered that his maybe a fragment of Munin's nummericals?

Comment: Sorry don't understand, please rephrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query with a huge result set would cause a spike like that without seeing a corresponding increase in the amount of queries. Do you have any disk I/O monitoring? There should be a big spike in that as well, if this was caused by a query.

Unfortunately, a postmortem examination is difficult without `general_log` enabled. The error log won't show successfully executed queries.

Going forward, what I have done to try and catch these problems is keep a window of query logs. Enable `general_log` and setup logrotate to keep a brief history of queries. If that's too performance intensive, you could also try using a tool like mk-query-digest together with tcpdump to capture queries.